# ActionMode menu icon is not shown

Tags: android, androidx, android-actionmode

I am trying setup contextual action bar when long click on a item in a recyclerview. But menu icon is not shown.

[image: action mode without icons shown]

Code is given below.

```
listAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : OnItemClickListener {

            override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
               ...
            }

            override fun onItemLongClick(position: Int): Boolean {

                if (actionMode != null) {
                    return false
                }

                val activity = activity as AppCompatActivity
                actionMode = activity.startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallback)


                return true
            }

        })
```

**Action Mode callback**

```
internal val actionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback {

    override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        when (item?.itemId) {
            R.id.item_delete -> {
                actionMode?.finish()
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        actionMode?.menuInflater?.inflate(R.menu.menu_context, menu)
        actionMode?.title = "delete"

        return true
    }

    override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {

        return false
    }

    override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {
        actionMode = null
    }
}
```

**menu_context.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_delete"
        android:title="@string/menu_option_text_delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
</menu>
```

**What I tried?**

- using non support lib version for `Activity` and `ActionMode`
- tried changing action mode background to see whether the issue with the theming
- [set SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS in onPrepareActionMode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32819031/7356355)

Did not work, even the action mode title is not shown.

I am using androidx, appCompat version : `1.1.0-rc01`

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this was a mistake in my part as pointed out in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139933357)

> ```
> override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
>      /*-->*/mode?.menuInflater?.inflate(R.menu.menu_context, menu)
>      return true
> }
> ```
>
> Note that you should use the passed in mode and not your own
>   ActionMode object to get the correct inflater.

Answer (score 1):

The soulution is to update the menus manually in onPrepareActionMode

```
@Override
  public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
  menu.findItem(R.id.menu_archive).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
  menu.findItem(R.id.menu_delete).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
  menu.findItem(R.id.menu_upload_to_cloud).setShowAsAction
  (MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
   return true;
 }
```

Comment: as I mentioned in the question, I already tried this, not working